# difference between all() and .all() for checking if an iterable is True everywhere

Tags: python, pytorch

I believe there are two ways of checking if a `torch.Tensor` has values all greater than 0. Either with `.all()` or `all()`, a Minimal Reproducible Example will illustrate my idea:

```py
import torch

walls = torch.tensor([-1, 0, 1, 2])

result1 = (walls >= 0.0).all()  # DIFFERENCE WITH BELOW???
result2 = all(walls >= 0.0)  # DIFFERENCE WITH ABOVE???

print(result1)  # Output: False
print(result2)  # Output: False
```

`all()` is builtin so I think I would prefer using that one, but most code I see on the internet uses `.all()` so I'm afraid there is unexpected behaviour.

Are they both behaving the exact same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is Python builtin, meaning that it only works using extremely generic interfaces. In this case, `all` treats the tensor as an opaque [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). It proceeds by iterating the elements of the tensor one-by-one, constructing a Python object for each one and then checking the truthiness of that Python object. That is *slow*, with several added layers of unnecessary inefficiency.

In contrast, [`Tensor.all`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.all.html#torch.all) knows what a `Tensor` object is, and can operate on it directly. It only needs to directly scan the tensors internal storage. No iterator protocol function calls, no intermediate Python objects.

`Tensor.all` will always be *far* more efficient, both in time and memory, that the builtin `all`.

Comment: Understood! Question, why does PyCharm warn me about using `Tensor.all`? https://i.imgur.com/sMgKC6r.png

Comment: Wow, I just tested the difference, and yes `all` is tremendously slower as you predicted. https://i.imgur.com/zAd8tVw.png

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows PyCharm is (incorrectly) guessing that the expression `(a >= b)` will be a `bool`. In reality, that expression evaluates to a tensor object. You can probably blame PyTorch for not providing better type hints / stubs